# undo stored procedure if there is an error on execution

Tags: sql-server

```
alter proc insert_toplam 'deneme2'
@str nvarchar(100)
as
begin
    insert into tblSekiller(sekilURL)
    select @str

    insert into tbl_fake
    select @str
end
```

i want prevent procedure from inserting `table_1` if somehow the procedure give an error on line `insert into tbl_fake` is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [TRY-CATCH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/try-catch-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and do the following:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;  

BEGIN TRY  

INSERT INTO tblSekiller(sekilURL)
SELECT @str

INSERT INTO tbl_fake
SELECT @str

END TRY  
BEGIN CATCH  
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0  
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION; -- if your insert generated an error, rollback  
END CATCH;  

IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0  
    COMMIT TRANSACTION;  -- otherwise, commit the transaction
GO
```